# How to import chart.js using ES6 syntax?

Tags: angularjs, charts, ecmascript-6

Using NPM, I downloaded and installed chart.js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js

Following the instructions I built and tested chart.js - it passed.

However, when I import it into my project like so:

```
import chartjs from 'chart.js'

export default angular.module('app', [
chartjs]
```

I get:

app.js:14099 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Chart due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Chart' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chart.js is not an Angular library. To use Chart.js with Angular you should use one of the convenience libraries that encapsulates its functionality within an Angular module or directives, e.g. [angular-chart.js](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/).